# Model hugggingface clipping responses

Tags: python, pycharm, huggingface, langchain

I am writing a Python code in pycharm, I connected the huggingface model via an IP key. everything works, starts, does not write about any error, but for some reason the model cuts off the answers. Here is the code (IP data removed):

```
import json
import requests
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

API_URL = ""
API_TOKEN = ""

def query(payload):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {API_TOKEN}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    data = json.dumps(payload)

    try:
        response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, data=data)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print("HTTP Error:", errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print("Error Connecting:", errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print("Timeout Error:", errt)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print("Error:", err)

# Создание экземпляра класса HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()

# Пример вложения запроса
text = "This is a test document."
query_result = embeddings.embed_query(text)

# Пример вложения документов
doc_result = embeddings.embed_documents([text])

while True:
    user_input = input("Введите ваш вопрос: ")
    if user_input.lower() == "выход":
        break

    data = query({
        "inputs": user_input,
        "options": {
            "max_length": 500
        }
    })
    generated_text = data[0]["generated_text"].strip()
    print("Ответ модели:", generated_text)
```